# Lazy match {x,y} ? y meaningless?

Tags: regex

What is the significance of 5 in {2,5}? it matches 2 to 5 of the preceeding token. This is a lazy match, and will match as few characters as possible before satisfying the next token.

I took example `abcccccabccc` and don't see any use of 5 in {2,5}? it matches only 2 consecutive a.

Can someone give any example where second parameter plays any role? ( 5 in this case {2,5}?)

```
abc{2,5} is greedy match 

First match: abccccc
Second match: abccc

abc{2,5}? is lazy match
First match: abcc
Second match: abcc
```

[reference](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this example >>

string: `123abcccccabc`

regex: `/123(abc{2,5}?)abc/`

will match `abccccc` in group #1, as `abc` behind the match is required to match as well.

Got it?

Comment: In this case /123(abc{2,5}?)abc/ and /123(abc{2,5})abc/ both will match abccccc correct?

Comment: @Praveen - Correct. And then test it with string `123abccabc` or `123abcccabc` and will see difference... It will try to match 2, if not possible 3, then 4 and the latest will try to match 5 of `c`, deppends on what is next **ahead** that sub-pattern. So it is lazy, but might be forced to go higher :)

Answer (score 2):

Say your regex is `"(.{0,10}?)"`. This would match quoted strings of up to 10 characters. For example

```
""
"foo"
"1234567890"
```

The laziness would ensure that quotes cannot be present inside the string. For instance, if you matched against a string with two quoted parts in it, the regex would only match the first one:

```
// "(.{0,10}?)"
"foo" "bar"
 ^^^
```

Leave out the lazy modifier and it would match both, erroneously capturing `foo" "bar` as the string contents.

```
// "(.{0,10})"
"foo" "bar"
 ^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. It's meaning depends on what follows it. For example `abc{2,5}?c` is different from `abc{2,5}?a`.